# PhpStorm built in webserver cannot upload files

Tags: php, forms, webserver, phpstorm

I'm trying to make a script for uploading a image in PhpStorm. The problem is that when I submit the form the page just keeps loading and from that point on something happens with the webserver because I can't load any page, so I have to restart the PhpStorm to make it work again. The script works fine with apache. Does anyone know what is the problem? Is it some kind of limitation of the built in webserver?

I tried this one: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp also, and doesn't work either.

Comment: Can we see the script? We need something to work with....

Comment: I got the exact same problem with phpstorm and it's nothing special just a simple form trying to upload some files like this:

<form method='post' action='script.php'>
    <input type='file' name='images'>
</form>

I'm using codeigniter to upload files and it does work when I try it with apache but phpstorm's built in server just freezes.
Please write if you find a solution I am searching some stuff on the web now too.