# Limit on POST request, 65KB image max

Tags: php, html, image, post, local

**Situation**

I'm trying to load an image into a php script through POST request.

**Problem**

The post action only works when the image is smaller than a size between 65.151 and 65.686 bytes. (I haven't figured out what the exact limit of bytes is that it will accept, i only know that 65.151 bytes works but 65.686 bytes and all above doesn't.)

**Symptoms**

When i try to upload an image that exceeds the limit that i described above, the webpage would hang. When i monitor the network in the browser it shows the POST request with a (pending) status. The body of the request contains the form with the image field. The reponse header is missing.

When i upload an image that doesn't exceed the limit, it shows the correct status and a response header and prints out the array containing the image with the correct size, ect..

There are no errors reported by php.

**Environment**

I'm running everything localy on my windows 7 laptop.
I have a windows php 5.6.8 engine which i installed seperatly.
I'm using Phpstorm to develop and run the application (it uses the php engine desribed above).
I'm using chrome and IE to test and troubleshoot.

**Settings**

I have fiddled alot with the following settings in php.ini:

- post_max_size
- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit

current settings:

- post_max_size = "2048M"
- upload_max_filesize = "2048M"
- memory_limit = 128M

**Code**

I've tried many differend approaches but currently i'm using the following code:

test-file-upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="uploadImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

uploadImage.php

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

**Directory structure**

- controller (dir)

  -> test-file-upload.html (file)

  -> uploadImage.php (file)

Could anybody give me an explanation why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2015/07/07**

I decided to take a different approach which resulted in bypassing the issue:
First i tried using different development tools to run the script.
I used Netbeans and Visual studio but they utilized the same php engine installation that php storm used. Both on VS and netbeans it failed to launch the webpage which i though was caused by the integrated webserver not beeing configured correctly. I didn't want to waste more time isolating the problem so i installed webmatrix on a different laptop to get a fresh new develop enviroment. Webmatrix detected the project as a php project and installed a fresh php engine (5.5 something). With use of the iis express webserver that webmatrix bundles with itself, i was able to launch the scripts and the 65KB+ limit was gone!

So after all this i can conclude that the code wasn't the problem but the develoment enviroment was. What exacly was causing the problem is not known to me, it could be the webserver which is integrated in phpstorm that caused the problem, or the php engine. If anyone as a idea i could test it out to find a propper solution. In the meantime, i'm happy with webmatrix.

**UPDATE 2015/07/10**

Everything is still working properly with the use of Webmatrix and it's build-in IIS webserver. But i still wanted to figure out the problem behind the 65KB+ limitation of phpstorm. After some research i learned that Phpstorm uses the build-in webserver of the PHP interpreter, which pointed the problem to the that. Then i came across a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261842/phpstorm-built-in-webserver-cannot-upload-files) which descibed the same problem i am having. They're upload script also runs fine on other webservers, but not on the php build-in webserver. So i'm almost certain the causing factor is the PHP build-in webserver.

If anyone knows the fix for this problem, please post it here. I will post a link to the solution on the other thread.